# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex, vuejs3

I am unable to fetch the current state that has been store in the component mounting stage.
Here i have initialized a ref variable isAdmin, after that in the mounting stage I want to get the current user email from the state and check if its the same as the email that i want and then i want to toggle isAdmin "true".
But when i am trying to access the email its saying email does not exist.

Here is have attached the vuex store on the right and from where i am accessing its on the left.
[check just above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0cey.png)

Vuex store.js

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import router from "../router";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged
} from "firebase/auth";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    user: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },

    CLEAR_USER(state) {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async login({ commit }, details) {
      const { email, password } = details;

      try{
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      } catch(error){
        alert(error)
        return
      }
      commit('SET_USER',auth.currentUser)

      router.push('/')
    },

    async register({ commit }, details) {
      const { email, password } = details;

      try{
        await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      } catch(error){
        alert(error)
        return
      }
      commit('SET_USER',auth.currentUser)

      router.push('/')
    },

    async logout({commit}){
      await signOut(auth)

      commit('CLEAR_USER')

      router.push('/login')
    },

    fetchUser({commit}) {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
        if(user === null){
          commit('CLEAR_USER')
        } else {
          commit('SET_USER',user)

          if(router.isReady() && 
            router.currentRoute.value.path === '/login')
            {
            router.push('/')
          }
        }
      })  
    }
  },
});
```

Here is the new of the UI with the div that i want show only when that email matches
[new div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKtIg.png)

Comment: You can't access state.user before the value was assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchUser` action is not finishing in time before you try accessing `state.user.email` in the mounted hook.  Instead, make isAdmin a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) that will set it's value as soon as `state.user.email` is updated (which itself should be a computed property according to [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html#accessing-state-and-getters)).

```js
const userEmail = computed(() => {
  return store.state?.user?.email;
})
const isAdmin = computed(() => {
  return userEmail.value === "abc@hotmail.com"
})
```

Comment: export default {
  setup() {
    // let isAdmin;
    const store = useStore();

    const isAdmin = computed(() => {
      return userEmail === "abc@hotmail.com";
    });

    const userEmail = computed(() => {
      return store.state.user.email;
    });

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      store.dispatch("fetchUser");
    });

    // onMounted(() => {

    // });
    // console.log(store.state.user, "user info");
    return { isAdmin };
  },
};          I am using it like this still not working

Comment: I've updated my answer to include optional chaining that should take care of any null errors.  It should work, here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-goldberg-itoe6u?file=/src/App.vue) to help.  The `fetchUser` action is a mock API call that will update the user's email after 5 seconds at which point the value of isAdmin should change from false to true

Comment: It will hide unhide some items in the UI if its true. like you might be knowing about the admin privileges.

Comment: You can check the new image I edited in the query post. Where i showed what am i doing with isAdmin

Comment: How you use isAdmin is up to you.  It will be true only if the `user.email` you fetch matches the e-mail you specify.  In my codesandbox example I force it to be true just for demonstration purposes.